# Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor ERROR

Tags: oracle, oracle21c

Downloaded the new Oracle 21c database. Once I downloaded it and tried to connect to database from sqldeveloper, it just shows me this connection error!

> Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with
> the following error:
> ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in
> connect descriptor   (CONNECTION_ID=YCUagZTAT4Cgqxrjq+ExEA==)

Tried deleting database folder and doing everything from the beginning, but it just shows the same error every time.

Comment: You said you *downloaded* 21c database, but - did you actually **install** that software?

Comment: Check with the listener what it sees (lsnrctl stat). And be sure that you started your database, and use services not SID